# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Comparable

Tags: java

I am work on an assignment, and I  needed to add a control loop. So was going to test it before I added it to the the existing code. I created a new java project and copy/pasted the class over. The new class (TestMain) gave me an error:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Comparable

The original class only has a warning stating that comparable is a raw type and should be parametrized.
I am reading that ints can not be cast as comparables, but I do not understand how it worked the first time.

Original Class that worked

```
package testing;

public class TestMatchMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparable[] innerCollection0 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Comparable[] innerCollection1 = { 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 };
    Comparable[] innerCollection2 = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    Comparable[][] collections = { innerCollection0, innerCollection1,
            innerCollection2 };
    TestMatch.match(collections);

}
}
```

Class that gave the error

```
package test1;

public class TestMAin {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparable[] innerCollection0 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Comparable[] innerCollection1 = { 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 };
    Comparable[] innerCollection2 = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    Comparable[][] collections = { innerCollection0, innerCollection1,
            innerCollection2 };
    TestMatch.match(collections);

}
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you post signature of `TestMatch.match` method?

Comment: They both compile fine for me.

Comment: probably you tried to compile the later one on lower JAVA version

Comment: Did you somehow create a Java 1.4 project? Auto-boxing has been available since Java 1.5.

Comment: public static void match(Comparable[][] collections) is this the signature?

Comment: What is your Java (compiler) version? Works fine for `javac 1.8.0_45`

Comment: java version 1.8.0_40     should the execution environment be CDC-1.0 or should it be set to J2SE-1.5?

Answer (score 0):

Added the Java-SE-1.7 library in the properties box per John Kugelman suspicions and it works.